# Can you put multiple inputs and text areas inside a dialog?

Tags: sapui5

Hi I am trying to put inputs and text areas inside a dialog but I keep getting the error Parsing error: Unexpected token Input [ESLINT: ()]. I have seen dialogs that have inputs on fiori documentation. So I know it is possible. Am I using the wrong control.

I have tried putting the input and text area in the content aggregation but that throws an error.

This is my code.

```
var dialog = new Dialog({
    title: "Create",
    type: "Message",
    content: {
        new Input({
               value = ""
        }),
        new TextArea({
                value: "",
                growing: true,
                growingMaxLines: 7
        }),
    },
    beginButton: new Button({
                text: "CREATE",
                press: function () {
                    dialog.close();
                }.bind(this)
    }),
    endButton: new Button({
                text: "CANCEL",
                press: function () {
                    dialog.close();
                }
    }),
    afterClose: function () {
            dialog.destroy();
    }
});
dialog.open();
```

The expected result is dialog where the user can enter data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the wrong control.

The problem is that you've made a tiny mistake by saying your content will only contain 1 element thanks to the curly brackets `{}` after your content declaration.

If you replace the curly brackets `{}` by square ones `[]`, you should be good to go.

Replacing your content declaration by the following will solve your issue:

```
...
    content: [
        new Input({
               value = ""
        }),
        new TextArea({
                value: "",
                growing: true,
                growingMaxLines: 7
        }),
    ],
...
```